# Calling a contact form in a certain page

Tags: javascript

I want to see my contact form in another page. I have now a link, www.xxx.com/index.php which is the contact form and dose work perfectly. I want to put it in another page let's say www.xxxx.com/YYY.php.

By opening www.xxxx.com/YYY.php, I want to see the contact form, too. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? By seeing a contact form "in another page" are you just wanting 2 URLs (e.g. *www.xxx.com/index.php* & *www.xxxx.com/YYY.php*) to point to the same contact form?

Comment: This seems not Drupal related since it's has the ".php" at the end of the URL.